# How to use Home PC as Internet Web Server?

Tags: webserver, dynamic

I have a java web application which is installed on Home PC.

[image: java web application on Home PC]

I have installed no-ip client on Home PC. Domain is paesia.no-ip.org

I have setup port forwarding to Home PC

[image: port forwarding to Home PC]

When I open http://paesia.no-ip.org:8080 , nothing is displayed. How can I use my home PC as internet web server?

Comment: I am able to connect to your site. Do you have an entry in your hosts file?

Comment: Seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks. Problem is that I've tested at home. It works fine when I've tested outside my home.

Comment: Have you set your private IP as your web servers in the configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an entry to your hosts file to map the domain name to the local IP address, then you should be able to use your domain name locally.